# Simple substitution

Tags: vim, vi

How do I substitute `&&&&&&&&&` with `&`? I have tried `:%s/&&&&&&&&&/&/g`but i only get more `&`.

Comment: For more information about the `:s` command see the following: `:h :s`, `:h :s_flags`, `:h :s\=`. The specific topic that discusses `&` can be found here: `:h s/\&`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `&` is special in the replacement part (it means "the whole matched string"), you have to escape it:

```
:%s/&&&&&&&&&/\&/g
```

*(Note the backslash before `&` in the replacement part.)*

Answer (score 4):

You need to escape `&` with `\` in replace string

```
:%s/&&&&&&&&&/\&/g
```

In replace string, `&` has a special meaning and contains matching string.

Therefore in you case, you are replacing nothing but match itself hence no change.

---

If your intension is to replace multiple `&` with a single one, then try following

```
:%s/&\+/\&/g
```

Answer (score 4):

You must escape `&` in the replacement section. Unescaped, `&` refers to the whole match.

```
:%s/&&&&&&&&&/\&/g
```

Answer (score -3):

You need a quantifier in the expression:

```
:%s/&\+/&/g
```

not sure if it works like that in vim, it is default regex, the plus sign tells it should capture any combination of one or multiple '&' signs,   using &{9} should find exactly nine

Comment: -1: No need to post incorrect answers after 4 correct ones have been posted... ;-)

Comment: How is the answer incorrect? the expression works fine and is more versatile than the other four? Of which one is edited to include my solution? I do not deserve these -1's :(

but hey, if it makes you feel better, +1 for you....